# Image manipulation in ActionScript 3.0 : realistically editing faces

Tags: actionscript-3, image-manipulation

I am a flash developer who has worked mostly on small ActionScript projects, in particular websites, but I am dipping my toes into image manipulation with AS3. I have a project I'm working on to develop an application which would allow a user to upload their own picture into a swf, and then, using a slider, they can alter the image to make themselves look thinner or fatter. The condition is that it should require minimal user input - so ideally the most I could expect from the user would be a couple of control points identifying certain areas of the face in response to prompts e.g. 'click on the centre of the chin' and when the user clicks, the position would be stored, but this would need to be used sparingly, if at all.

So far, I have been able to use the FileReference class to handle the upload, and I am experimenting with using the DisplacementMap filter to edit certain parts of the uploaded image, but I am having serious trouble implementing this in a manner that would allow realistic deformation of the facial features in the image uploaded.

Is there anything that exists that might run along the same lines and that provides an explanation/source code I could look at to get a better idea of how to go around doing this? Or if there are any other ideas on how to manipulate and distort the image that doesn't use the DisplacementMap Filter?

Any feedback and help is greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

see http://sakri.net/technology/flash/flex/convolution_filter/ConvolutionFilterExplorer.html
(source code available)